# OpenCV High Dynamic Range in Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am new to OpenCV with Python and was looking for some tutorial on HDR usage in OpenCV using Python. I have found a couple of [links](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/photo/doc/hdr_imaging.html) with small snippets to illustrate the usage in C++ however I was unable to find any tutorial in Python. Is their an extension of HDR in OpenCV-Python? If so, can anyone provide with a link of some tutorial for the same? If not, can anyone explain how to go about implementing our own functions like ToneMap in OpenCV-Python?

Comment: Google `HDR in OpenCV-Python`

Answer (score 0):

There is a [nice Python tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.0/d2/df0/tutorial_py_hdr.html) on official OpenCV website about HDR images generation/tonemapping using the high-level functions showcased in your original link.

About HDR image i/o, you can build OpenCV from source with OpenEXR dependency to enable read/write of 16bit (half) and 32bit (float) EXR image files.