# Python opencv // strange results on .EXR image

Tags: python, opencv

I'm starting to use opencv and I'm getting strange result when I'm reading my .exr file.

I just want to get values of some pixels to start but that doesn't seems to work.
Is there an issue with EXR, or is it something else ?

Here is my basic code :

```
import cv2

imgSource = '*path to my image*'
logo = cv2.imread(imgSource)

print logo[10,13]
print logo[13,16]
```

The output I get is this :

```
[2 2 2]
[2 2 2]
```

This is not the intended values, and the 2 regions should give different things

Comment: EXR is an high dynamic range format image. Its values can be outside the normal 16-bit or 32-bit range depending upon the EXR format. Perhaps that is your issue. When you read the EXR format it may be getting clipped.

Comment: I've created the file for the sake of the test, the values in the image are not exceeding 0.5 (or 127), that's why I'm really confused.

Comment: If you are just getting started and have no legacy codebase, you should maybe consider using Python3 which has been out for 11 years, rather than Python2.

Comment: If you want the image to retain its dynamic range, you should read it with `IMREAD_UNCHANGED` so it is not coerced into 8-bit.

Comment: I do have code knowledge :)  I just wanted to try using opencv for personal projects, the softwares i'm using are Python2 friendly that's why I'm more used to it.

Comment: ah yes @MarkSetchell, the values are more logical with this argument !

Comment: Ok so I had trouble understanding how the coordinates where working, but thanks to you @MarkSetchell it's all good now, thanks !! :)

Comment: You probably need to build OpenCV with OpenEXR enabled. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30560236/opencv-high-dynamic-range-in-python/56961823#56961823, for example, from a similar topic.

Comment: Thanks @fmw42, definitively a usefull doc !